# No more FlurryAnalytics and FlurryAppCircle?

Tags: iphone, ios, flurry

When i download the flurry sdk v4.0.6, there are folders for flurry and flurryads but no folders for FlurryAnalytics and FlurryAppCircle. I need to get the libFlurryAnalytics.a and libFlurryAppCircle.a files to run an app passed by my senior. Anyway I can download FlurryAnalytics and FlurryAppCircle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4.x Flurry iOS SDK is modularized to allow developers to select exactly the components they wish to integrate into their app. Please note that FlurryAPI (2.x) or FlurryAnalytics (3.x) is now just Flurry. Replace FlurryAPI/FlurryAnalytics in existing calls that relate to capturing analytics data with Flurry. Similarly, replace FlurryAPI or FlurryAppCircle/FlurryClips/FlurryReengagement in existing calls that relate to app recommendations with FlurryAds. The new integration instructions are available inside the SDK folder, and at support.flurry.com. However, if you still need the older version of the SDK, please write to support@flurry.com.
(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: 4.x has removed the ability of custom ad UI rendering